# Monogame audio not working

Tags: c#, audio, xna, monogame

Somehow, even after following every tutorial I could find on the topic, I could not find a way to simply run my game with a song in the background. I tried everything, but it should be as simple as [**this**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=inJK28LdGbI&index=27), right?

I tried converting my audio files to every extension I've heard working with Monogame, ended up using .mp3 again but that just causes [**this**](http://gyazo.com/dc0f2722f71b28776b4955022f83b36d) to happen.

This should be something incredibly simple I am missing, but I am looking for an answer for two days straight now.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You need to convert your audio files to .xnb with XNA's content pipeline, like any other content.

Comment: I read something about that, but I haven't seen anyone doing that. Also, how do I do that?

Comment: Read monogame doc, it's clearly explained. Basically you install VS2010 express and XNA, put your content in, build the project and retrieve the xnbs. [This link](http://rbwhitaker.wikidot.com/monogame-accessing-the-xna-content-pipeline) is probably the best on the subject.

Comment: Thanks, I'll read into it!

Comment: Could you help me a bit regarding building the project and retrieving the xnbs? Where do I put the content, how do I access it through code etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found an answer! It appears VS2013 doesn't allow .wav files as songs, so I had to make it a soundeffect, or something like that (I still don't fully get it). It works now though, and I'll keep this post up for reference!

Answer (score 0):

What Pierre-Luc said is correct. You need to convert your audio file to XNB, using either VS2010 or this tool: https://xnacontentcompiler.codeplex.com/

After compiling the audio file, you just load it as any other content file. And yes, as a SoundEffect.

Comment: Why would I need to use 2010? I use 2013 and it worked (not ideal, but it did).

Comment: Well, I have heard that some people got it working with 2013. It's just that it's usually not easy getting XNA to work with 2012+. Good for you :)